# Remove duplicated objects from array but also increase quantity

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this list:

```js
const list = [
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'BB', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 2 },
]
```

And the output I'm looking for should look like:

```js
const newlist = [
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 2 },
  { name: 'BB', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 3 },
]
```

This code removes duplicates, but I just can't figure it out how to increase quantity when duplicate is present.

```js
const setObj = new Set()
const result = list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!setObj.has(item.name)) {
    setObj.add(item.name)
    acc.push({ name: item.name, quantity: item.quantity })
  }

  // for (const iterator of list) {
  //   if (setObj.has(item.name)) {
  //     console.log(' ~ file: Untitled-1 ~ line 15 ~ iterator', iterator)
  //   }
  // }

  console.log()
  return acc
}, [])
```

Comment: When you're pushing the object, do `quantity: item.quantity * list.filter(i=> i.name === item.name).length`.

Comment: Tried that but getting  
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 2 },
  { name: 'BB', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 2 }

cc should be 3

Comment: Ah, right, because `quantity` isn't necessarily 1 all the time. Yeah, you'd have to sum, and at that point, you might as well you `reduce` for the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different object approach that uses Object.values() to return resultant array

```js
const list = [
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'BB', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 2 },
]

const group = {};

list.forEach(e => {    
   const o =  group[e.name] = group[e.name] || {...e, quantity: 0}
   o.quantity += e.quantity
})

const res = Object.values(group)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: i will give this one as best answer because what I've noticed that quantity for other also increase after it's being used multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` then find element in result array, if it's doesn't exist `push` it to `array`, otherwise `add` current element `quantity` to `element` that has been found in result `array`.

Code:

```js
const list=[{name:"AA",quantity:1},{name:"AA",quantity:1},{name:"BB",quantity:1},{name:"CC",quantity:1},{name:"CC",quantity:2}];

const res = list.reduce((acc, e) => {
  const found = acc.find(x => e.name === x.name)
  found ? found.quantity += e.quantity : acc.push(e)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop to either create a new entry, or increment the current one:

```
let newList = [];
list.forEach((e)=>{
   let el=newList.find(n => n.name==e.name);
   if (el) el.quantity+=e.quantity;
   else newList.push(e);
});
```

Comment: Do not use `map` for side effects. `map` returns a transformed array. Use it, or use `forEach` instead.

Comment: yes thank you this is what i need, on top of that i iwll use forEach thank you both

Comment: Why use find() twice for the same array element?

Comment: Because it was easier to type :P. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution here is to use an object, because that's what you're asking to build: a thing with unique named keys.

```
const list = [
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'AA', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'BB', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'CC', quantity: 2 },
];

const filtered = list.reduce((tally, e) => {
  if (!tally[e.name]) tally[e.name] = 0;
  tally[e.name] += e.quantity
  return tally;
}, {});
```

Comment: I'm quite sure i was looking to get array of objects and not object with unique keys, but this is close

Comment: That's essentially an Object.entries() away, but you can also do the forEach iteration mentioned in the other answer.